# SQL query with double SUM statements

Tags: php, mysql, database

Having 2 tables:
- topics
- posts

Posts have "rating" feature:

```
topic 1, post 1, rating 2
topic 1, post 1, rating 2
topic 1, post 2, rating 1
```

Topics have "views" feature:

```
topic 1, views 5
topic 1, views 3
```

I wants to get sum of post ratings in all topics and sum views of all topics.
The my *bad* SQL:

```
SELECT
  forum_id,
  topic_id,
  SUM(t1.rating),
  SUM(t2.views)
FROM
  posts t1
LEFT JOIN
  topics t2 ON t1.topic_id = t2.topic_id
GROUP BY
  t1.topic_id
```

It returns not correctly values, i think - by joining reasons - they need to grouping 2 times.

What i can do for resolve?

**ADDED AFTER READING RESPONSE:**

```
SELECT
    t1.`forum_id`,
    t1.`topic_id`,
    SUM(t1.`rating`) AS rating,
    t3.`views` AS views
FROM
    `forum_ratings_posts` t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM(t2.`views`) AS views,
        t2.`topic_id`
    FROM
        `forum_ratings_topics` t2
    GROUP BY
        t2.`topic_id`
) t3 ON t1.`topic_id` = t3.`topic_id`
GROUP BY
    t1.`topic_id`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this helps. This approach makes use of `LEFT JOIN` on a derived table and does the SUMMING for topics table in that derived table. The `LEFT JOIN` will ensure that you have an entry from the posts table irrespective of the presence of the corresponding entry in the topics table. Let me know if you need more information.

```
SELECT
  t1.forum_id,
  t1.topic_id,
  SUM(t1.rating),
  temp.t2_sum
FROM
    posts t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(views) AS t2_sum, topic_id FROM topics GROUP BY 
topic_id) AS temp 
ON t1.topic_id = temp.topic_id
GROUP BY
 t1.topic_id
```

Comment: I made minor changes to the code. Please try the updated query and post the error message if that does not work.

Comment: Sure. No problem. Also, make sure you understand the concept since something like this can be used in multiple places. There might also be additional ways to do this but this is the approach that I normally take.